# Webform conditional from Civicrm checksum

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, checksum

I use drupal 7 and latest civicrm.

I direct people to my form using the checksum. I would like to not display email field and GDPR opt in field if they arrive at the form via checksum. If they arrive at the form without checksum I would like email/opt in to be visible.

I know how to use conditionals within the form (eg if email address is present then display field X) but I can’t work out how to do it from the initial check sum - I feel it ought to be possible. Can anyone help?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is possible with the below adjustments on the webform.

- Add a disabled textfield on your webform and set its default value to a token or checksum value from the URL.
- Now, add the condition on this element to hide email when it's value is not blank.

Update after Karing's comment - If you need to hide the field from the webform, maybe use a little css like `display:none` for the same.

Comment: Yes that should work! Alternatively you could also try to just check off / select the checksum field in the CiviCRM Config section;

Comment: And you can always add other values to the webform link like ?myvar=1&cs=xxxx

Comment: Hello very helpful people! Thank you! I fear I need a little more! Jitendra - I can create a private civicrm field is that what you mean when you say hidden? When I created a private civicrm checksum field I couldn't get the conditional thing to work (I only had the option of is shown/is not shown and as the field was private it seemd to think it was always not shown). I wonder if you could elaborate a little more?

Comment: Karin G - by this do you mean under the civicrm webfom tab select checksum - I did that and marked it private but as above couldn't get the conditional to recognise when an individual had one and when they didn't

Comment: RayWright - how do I do that - that sounds very useful! Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can not make the field private or you can’t use conditionals on it if you want to hide it - use some css display:none

Comment: Agree with the above comment. Have also updated the answer with the above suggestion.

Comment: Can't you do a conditional off of the "Existing Contact" field? If I'm reading the question right then that field is already present but hidden on the form.

Comment: @CarolineB the checksum in your URL is a query string, i.e. www.mysite?cid1={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum} you can add and variable you'd like (myvar=1234) and then throw that in a default value for a field [current-page:query:myvar]. I'm not sure you'd need it in this case but it's additional data you can use in the webform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) and in hook check if URL parameter for checksum is present then you can remove specific webform form elements like this:

$form['submitted']['element_form_key']['#access'] = FALSE;